# Making Curvy shape using CSS

Tags: html, css, overlay, css-gradients

Hi I want make a grayish (#444) curvy overlay on a banner image of my website. I am attaching a image of what I want.

[image]

Comment: Don't see any curvy shapes in the image. Please highlight which one you are trying to create.

Comment: You could just set the blurred image as the background of the div.

Comment: The curvy gray overlay that is over the building image. @Harry

Comment: @MueedullahK. That seems more like a part of the image (or) a radial gradient which goes from transparent (on top of the building) to a semi-transparent gray (at the end). Creating concave shapes using CSS is very tough and radial gradients have low support, I'd advise you to use images or SVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by using CSS Radial Gradients.

You can either use an additional div or if you want you could use pseudo elements.

I have used multiple div's to show you how it would look all built together.

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 21.875%, transparent 0%, transparent 20%, #444 45%);
  background: radial-gradient(at 100% 21.875%, transparent 0%, transparent 20%, #444 45%);
  background-size: 100% 225%;
}
.overlay .text {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/300/" width="100%" height="auto" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Stewart, I really appreciate this help. Kindly increase the curve, means make the curve more deeper and round. Also make the css code cross browser,

Comment: @MueedullahK. the code should be fine cross browser. Ive increased the curve and make it deeper and it should be sufficient

Comment: thanks, what you did to increase the curve? I want to know so I can play around and adjust it as per my need.

Comment: A mixture between changing the background size height and the radial gradient position. The change of colour stops is also within the radial gradient. If this is all working, an accept would be much welcomed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am very close to it but just need make the curve more deeper slighter, just a bit or two.

Comment: deeper? in which way? Ive made it more of a curve by a small amount and hope this is fine.

Comment: can you just make the curve deeper slighter a bit more please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple backgrounds and `radial-gradient`. [Here's an example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrLELZ)

**EDIT** Here's the CSS from that example.

```
#banner{
   width:400px;
   height:200px;
   background:radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 100% 50%,rgba(68,68,68,0) 60%,#444 70%),url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Sun-in-the-sky.jpg/800px-Sun-in-the-sky.jpg);
   background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Would be better if you add the code within the answer itself instead of leaving it at an external site :)

Answer (score 0):

## Absolute positioned div as overlay

Using an overlay and position absolute you can create the gray overlay.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #444;
  background-image: url("http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/");
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 150%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 100% 50%, transparent 40%,  #444 60%);
  top: -25%;
}
.container p {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Persijn, I really appreciate this help. Kindly increase the curve, means make the curve more deeper and round. Also make the css code cross browser,

Comment: @MueedullahK. Works in chrome: 47. IE Edge 25. Firefox 43. You should have mentioned the support you are going for in your question.

Comment: I want to be cross browser friendly means it should work on almost all browsers, at least make the curve deeper please.

Comment: i did make it deeper?